# Removing "feed" folder in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've looked everywhere and cannot figure this out and appreciate anyone's help on this:

I have several links that need to be redirected and they look like this:

```
http://www.DOMAINNAME.com/about-us/feed
```

I just want to remove the folder "/feed" in those URLs and everything I have tried doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^about-us/feed$ http://www.DOMAINNAME.com/about-us [R=301,L]
```

Also does not work:

```
redirect 301 about-us/feed http://www.DOMAINNAME.com/about-us
```

Thanks again for the help. I have a LOT of other redirects to do but will start here. I normally don't have any issues with these but for whatever reason these are causing me some issues. Plus it's Monday so I'm sure that doesn't help any :)

Comment: Looks fine. Are you sure you've a `RewriteEngine On` directive somewhere? Might you be missing a `RewriteBase /`?

Comment: I'm not missing any of the basics I have both RewriteEngine On and RewriteBase / too :/

Comment: In that case, double check that a prior regex is not matching the url. (Or more simply, place it first.)

Comment: I'll give that shot. Thanks for the response and I'll let you know what I find :)

Comment: It definitely was the order of things. I moved some items around and now they all work beautifully! Thanks for the help Denis!